# Folder.searchFiles() method raises "Invalid argument: q" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Given the following Google Apps Script code snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxx').searchFiles('123')
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next()
      Logger.log(file.getName())
  }
}
```

I'm getting:

> Invalid argument: q (line x, file "Code")

from the line with `while (files.hasNext())` statement.

The line doesn't contain any error I'm aware of. The funny thing is when I exchange `.searchFiles('123')` with `.getFiles()`, the error doesn't appear and the code executes.

Does it mean that there's a problem with the object that `.searchFiles('123')` returns (it should return `FileIterator` object)? Unfortunately, Javascript only checks the return data type at runtime so I cannot really see if it's correct until I run it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the function documentation of [`searchFiles`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)), the expected argument is a query string that conforms to the syntax described in the Google Drive API's ["Search for Files " guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)

> Gets a collection of all files in the user's Drive that match the given search criteria. The search criteria are detailed in the [Google Drive SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters). Note that the `params` argument is a query string that may contain string values, so take care to escape quotation marks correctly (for example `"title contains 'Gulliver\\'s Travels'"` or `'title contains "Gulliver\'s Travels"'`).

Note that [Drive v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) uses `title` for the filename, and [Drive v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters) uses `name` for the filename. Apps Script's advanced service client library [`Drive`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) uses v2, so this may be the syntax used by the Drive Service (`DriveApp`) as well.

The reason the error message does not appear on the line with `searchFiles` is because the return value is a [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), rather than the actual results. This (and most) iterators are lazily-evaluated, and thus your search query is not actually executed until you call `files.hasNext()`.

To resolve this issue, you must indicate what should be searched and how, i.e. provide the **Field** and the **Operator**, not just the **Value**.

```
function foo() {
  const queries = ["fullText contains '123'",
                   "mimeType='" + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + "'"];
  const matches = queries.map(function (qs) {
    return getMatchingFiles_(qs);
  });
  // Log the results in the Apps Script logger. (Use console.log for Stackdriver)
  matches.forEach(function (queryResult, i) {
    Logger.log("Results for query #" + i
               + ", \"" + queries[i] + "\" are:");
    queryResult.forEach(function (file) {
      Logger.log(file.getId() + ": '" + file.getName() + "'");
    });
  });
}

function getMatchingFiles_(query, folderId) {
  // Default to DriveApp.searchFiles if no folder ID given.
  folder = folderId ? DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId) : DriveApp;
  const search = folder.searchFiles(query);
  const results = [];
  while (search.hasNext())
    results.push(search.next());

  return results;
}
```

Comment: Switching from 'name' to 'title' per your answer resolved this for me. The reference documentation they linked led me here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters#fn5 with no mention of 'title'.